# Where do I place a custom membership provider in my project architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, n-tier-architecture

I started learning how to build N-Tier web applications 4 months ago and I still don’t fully understand where to place everything. My architecture is based on the book “Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns” by Scott Millett and is as follows:

- Project.Controllers
- Project.Infrastructure
- Project.Model
- Project.Repository.NHibernate
- Project.Services
- Project.UI.Web.MVC

In his case study he used the standard Membership provider in his Infrastructure project. If I ever wanted to create another web application I could easily add the Infrastructure project to the solution and have membership ready to use.

But I want to create my own custom Membership provider that uses NHibernate. Should I create a service for it in my Services project and create a repository for it in my Repository.NHibernate project? Or should I still use the Infrastructure project and create those in there so that I can reuse it in other projects?

Comment: This may depend on how reusable you want the provider.  For ASP.Net web forms not MVC we created a custom provider and placed all the code in separate class library in a Company.Security base namespace, and the code is self contained and not part of the main project. Reasons for us is we can reuse the custom provider in another project (copy the dll) and in most cases it is not a direct relation to business rules.  You can as you suggested integrate it throughout the structure of your app (Repository in Repository, Model in Model etc) but for me security items tend to be more self contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I completely agree with Peter and Modika, I wanted to add a few things.

When designing your app you need to understand the reason for putting those things in separate projects and have a thorough understanding of Separation of Concerns.  Meaning, you need to know what you are separating and why why you are concerned about it.

I haven't read that particular book, so I have no comment on the authors approach.  Regardless, before going off and believing how the author named things is the "professional" way of doing it, stop and consider not only your application but also how things like the .net framework itself are structured.

On any given project you may have to produce several types of artifacts including: data access code, object model, UI, business logic, etc.

There are several natural boundary areas.  Such as you may want the data access code separated out in case you need to swap out permanent storage options or even just to swap out access methods like using LINQ, NHibernate or what have you.

You might want the possibility for the object model to be reused in other solutions; or you might even want to support swapping out UI pieces like moving from WebForms to MVC to whatever..  You might even have a need to apply different business logic to the object model depending on how it's used or who is using it.

That said not every application has the same structural needs.  For example, the object model might be completely meaningless without the business logic; or, more likely, there might be certain logic that absolutely must be merged in with the class definitions while other logic is specific to how the library is used.  If the former is the case then you have a strong reason to put the business logic in the exact same project/assembly as the class definitions.  If the latter, then you might want it separated out into other assemblies and implement Interface definitions for the objects.

It's been my experience that if you just don't know, keep it together because that's the simplest option with an eye on refactoring what you want out later if the situation demands it.

If you over engineer early on then you increase project time/cost for what amounts to a *perceived potential benefit* which may never be realized later; this is rarely a good decision.  It has the further problem that you have no idea what you may need down the road and separating now will likely mean you increase project time today and *still* have to refactor later, which is a double whammy.  The truly professional developer, IMHO, takes cost/ dev time into consideration when evaluating potential solutions.

---

Now, getting to the specific requirement about a custom built membership provider that has a high probability of being reused in other projects.  The custom provider should be in it's own project and namespace.  I'd probably use a namespace like `Company.Security`.  This would provide the best method of portability allowing you to reuse just the relevant code without dragging along all sorts of other things that are particular to this one project.

Because it uses the provider model you shouldn't have code in your other projects that need to directly reference this one.  Just use the interfaces that already exist.

Answer (score 3):

Don't over engineer your solutions, there is no real right or wrong with these things. Do the simplest thing to solve your problem and deliver the functionality.

So the big question is why do that when you can just use the SqlMembershipProvider to achieve the same thing (unless of course you are changing the table structure that is created with the aspnet_regsql command)

Anyway questions aside, I tend to follow the Microsoft conventions for namespacing. So in your case I would create a new class library in your Solution called YourCompany.Web.Security and then create the Provider classes there in a namespace called YourCompany.Web.Security.HibernateMembershipProvider. All your repositories and services and other junk would go in this assembly.

Now the bigger problem you have is an academic question about the datastore. In my experience it is better not to place identity and "general" profile data in the same database as your application data goes. So this new assembly should check the database instance that you are connecting to and create tables etc to support your membership needs (assuming you are implementing a full provider)

You might need to write your own web/windows app to manage the users as well.

So I'd really question the value of what you are doing when all this exists already with the SqlMembershipProvider.

Having said all this there's a lot to be said for investigating the new Microsoft Identity Foundation (WIF) features of .net 4.5 and using azure to manage you identity data. It's pretty easy to setup.

Comment: When I create an user with Membership I also want to insert some personal data to another table. So if I use the standard Membership provider, Membership will create the user. After that I do another insert with NHibernate to store some personal data. If something goes wrong, NHibernate will rollback. But Membership will not rollback because they are not committed in the same transaction. The user gets created, but the personal data is not inserted. I'm afraid that this may happen and that's the reason I want a custom Membership provider.

Comment: you should only share key material between these concerns. nothing is stopping you from querying 2 databases for this info. Read Eric Evans' Domain Driven Design.